# working with parameter from the constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, copy

I have following problem:
whats the best way to work on with a object which i got as parameter from my constructor?
I don't want to work with the copy because, the initial object won't change.

```
Obj obj;

myclass::myclass(Obj& obj)
{
  this->obj = obj; //copy
}

void myclass::doSometh()
{
 obj.add(....); //working with the copy
}
```

My solution would be to use a pointer:

```
Obj* obj;

void myclass::myclass(Obj& obj)
{
  this->obj = &obj; 
}

void myclass::doSometh()
{
 obj->add(....); 
}
```

or

```
    Obj* obj;

   myclass::myclass(Obj* obj)
    {
      this->obj = obj; 
    }

    void myclass::doSometh()
    {
     obj->add(....); 
    }
```

what do you thing about my solution? or are there better solutions?

Comment: Your solution may not work, depends on the lifetime of `Obj` object, where it's coming from, similar to the third one. You should read about C++ object lifetime and dynamic memory management if you are coming from a language with auto memory management like Java, Python, C# etc.

Comment: so if the initial object doesn't exist anymore would have problems with my pointers, but whats the best solution for this, using a smart pointer?, well i read a lot about it, but i still can't find the best solution for this

Comment: you don't need use this inside class

Comment: You can indeed use smart pointers, or you can use a copy. What's best depends on how heavyweight `Obj` is and on some other factors. Sometimes it's best to use a copy, sometimes not.

Comment: in this case i don't want to work with the copy because the changes should also be done on the original object which i passed as parameter

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with using a pointer member-variable to avoid making a copy. But you do need to be confident that the object being pointed to, `Obj`, will outlive the `MyClass` which contains the pointer.

Also, I recommend using the constructor initializer list to initialize the pointer directly:

```
class MyClass {
 private:
  Obj* obj_;
 public:
  MyClass(Obj* obj) : obj_(obj) { }
};
```

In a similar way you could also have a reference member-variable but it restricts what you can do with the class. e.g it will not be assignable:

```
class MyClass {
 private:
  Obj& obj_;
 public:
  MyClass(Obj& obj) : obj_(obj) { }
};
```

If you are not confident of the lifetime of the object being pointed to consider `std::weak_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`:

```
#include <memory>

struct Obj { };

class MyClass {
 private:
  std::weak_ptr<Obj> obj_;
 public:
  MyClass(std::weak_ptr<Obj> obj) : obj_(std::move(obj)) { }
  void doSomething() {
    std::shared_ptr<Obj> obj = obj_.lock();
    if (obj) {
      // do something with obj...
    }   
  }
};

int main() {
  std::shared_ptr<Obj> obj = std::make_shared<Obj>();
  MyClass mc(obj);
}
```

Comment: using initializer list for the constructor is a good idea, but function and their parameter, i can't use it.
well what do you mean by being confident of the lifetime of the object, that i make sure that it lifes long enough?.
i heared using pointers in this case could cause major ownership problems

Comment: @Sleicreider Sorry, I don't understand why you can't use the constructor initializer list?

Comment: @Sleicreider Regarding the lifetime of the object, I mean if you can be confident that `Obj` will be alive for at least as long as `MyClass`. I'll try to make it more clear.

Comment: for constructors you can ofc use initializer lists, but if I would pass the object as parameter of a normal function, i cant use them

Comment: @Sleicreider Yes, of course but I understood your question was about a parameter passed in a **constructor** being stored in a member variable. If your situation is different to this I suggest editing your question as the answers may be more relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a reference:

```
 Obj& obj;

 myclass::myclass( Obj& obj ) : obj(obj) {}
```

Comment: i think, this also would just create a copy, and if i work with the copy the object which i passed as parameter won't be changed

Comment: @Sleicreider, No, it won't make a copy. You're initializing the reference with the parameter. It's like doing `int &ref = someInt;`.

Comment: oh ok, i thought with Obj obj; with out the & ._.
and there would be no problems with life time?

Comment: Using a reference as a class member makes the class uncopiable.  Use a pointer instead.

Comment: i heard with normal pointers i would have ownership problems and life time problems